# Customized object initialization in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have an older fabric.js project that I want to modernize.
In this project there are user defined attributes that should be considered during object initialization.
The following example should show how it was solved in the original project:

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.initialize = (function (initialize) {
    return function (element, options) {
        let lock = element.lock;
        element.lockMovementX = lock; 
        element.lockMovementY = lock;
        return fabric.util.object.extend(initialize.call(this, element, options), {});
})(fabric.Object.prototype.initialize);
```

This part of the project should be changed to typescript.
Just following the recommendations of my IDE would lead to the following:

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.initialize = (function (initialize) {
    return (element: fabric.IObjectOptions | undefined, options?: fabric.IObjectOptions | undefined) => {
        // do something
        return fabric.util.object.extend(initialize.call(element, options), {});
    };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.initialize);
```

The objects are now initialized incorrectly.
I don't find the problem myself and haven't found any examples of customised object initialization.

I would be happy if someone could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here's the solution:

```
 fabric.Object.prototype.initialize = (function (initialize) {
    return function (_options) {
      const options = {...yourCustomOptions, ...(_options ?? {})}
      
      return initialize.apply(this, [options]);
    };
  })(fabric.Object.prototype.initialize);
```